# How do I read the output of a region in Numenta's HTM architecture?

Tags: classification, nupic

Suppose I've trained a region to recognize the 2D image of a letter "A". How do I interface this to an external module that wants signals (possibly fuzzy) of the form A or not A?

Answer (score 2):

We've been working with NuPIC not for images processing but for transactions processing, and so far we have gotten very good results.

What we do is connect the classifier node to a efector node who writes into a socket the result of the inference.

Maybe we need more detail about your question. If you've trained a NuPIC network for identifying just the letter "A" then maybe you have a classifier trained with 2 categories: lets say 1 for "A" and 0 for anything else. In this case you can take the output of the classifier via an efector node that conects to your interface, may be a socket or a database.

Regards